# Running multiple neural networks in parallel on cpu

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytorch, multiprocessing

I am trying to run multiple instances of same neural network training in pytorch but with different hyperparameters. For example different learning rate, optimizer etc.
I tried to create a multiprocessing.Pool but I am getting an error:

```
Runtime error: Unable to handle autograd's threading in combination with fork-based multiprocessing. See https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/wiki/Autograd-and-Fork
```

Here is the sample code to give an idea of what I am doing:

```
def run_one_instance(idx=0):
    lr = choose_random([0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1])
    optimizer = choose_random(["SGD", "Adam"])
    num_hidden_layers = choose_random([2,3,4,5])
    model = create_model(num_hidden_layers, lr, optimizer)
    model.train()
    return model.evaluate()

def run_multiple_instances(num_instances=40):
    pool_obj = multiprocessing.Pool()
    result = pool_obj.map(run_one_instance, range(0, num_instances))
    return result
```

So is there something I am doing wrong? Is there any other way to run multiple neural networks in parallel (on cpu or gpu)?

Answer (score 0):

As [the link in the error message explains](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/wiki/Autograd-and-Fork), use Python's multiprocessing's `spawn` context instead of the `fork` context. Like so:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp


ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')


def run_one_instance(idx=0):
    lr = choose_random([0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1])
    optimizer = choose_random(["SGD", "Adam"])
    num_hidden_layers = choose_random([2,3,4,5])
    model = create_model(num_hidden_layers, lr, optimizer)
    model.train()
    return model.evaluate()

def run_multiple_instances(num_instances=40):
    pool_obj = ctx.Pool()
    result = pool_obj.map(run_one_instance, range(0, num_instances))
    return result
```

The `ctx` object has the same API as the multiprocessing module. See [the Python multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) for more info about multiprocessing contexts (e.g. `spawn` and `fork`).